# pytest access parameters from function scope fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("argument", [1])
def test_func(self, function_context, argument)
```

And I have the following function scope fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def function_context(session_context):
    # .... do something ....
```

Is it possible to access the current function argument from within the `function_context` fixture?

In my case - I want to get the value `1` that is being passed in `parametrize` from within `function_context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixtures in `pytest` are instantiated before the actual tests are ran, so it shouldn't be possible to access the test function argument at the fixture definition stage. However, I can think of two ways to bypass this:

#### 1. Monkeypatching

You can [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html) the fixture, i.e. temporarily change some of its attributes, based on the parameter of the function that uses this fixture. For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def function_context(session_context):
    # .... do something ....

@pytest.mark.parametrize("argument", [1])
def test_func(self, function_context, argument, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(function_context, "number", argument) # assuming you want to change the attribute "number" of the function context
    # .... do something ....
```

Although your fixture is valid for the scope of the function only anyhow, monkeypatching is also only valid for a single run of the test.

#### 2. Parametrizing the fixture instead of the test function

Alternatively, you can also choose to [parametrize the fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize) itself instead of the `test_func`. For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', params=[0, 1])
def function_context(session_context, request):
    param = requests.param # now you can use param in the fixture
    # .... do something ...

def test_func(self, function_context):
    # .... do something ...
```